# Only one record from the txt file being loaded into table

Tags: mysql

I have a txt file where the records look like this:

```
1194    8710    2009-01-04  Critical    42  151.35  0.07    Express Air 8.33    3.71    1.93    Tamara Dahlen   Ontario Ontario Corporate   Office Supplies Paper   """While you Were Out"" Message Book, One Form per Page"    Wrap Bag    0.35    2009-01-06  
2272    16326   2010-05-10  High    39  147.46  0.06    Regular Air 14.13   3.71    1.93    Bill Donatelli  Ontario Ontario Corporate   Office Supplies Paper   """While you Were Out"" Message Book, One Form per Page"    Wrap Bag    0.35    2010-05-10  
8376    59815   2010-12-15  Not Specified   14  51.56   0.09    Regular Air -1.06   3.71    1.93    Christy Brittain    British Columbia    West    Consumer    Office Supplies Paper   """While you Were Out"" Message Book, One Form per Page"    Wrap Bag    0.35    2010-12-17  
8179    58470   2011-06-08  High    13  49.08   0.06    Regular Air -0.31   3.71    1.93    Barry Blumstein British Columbia    West    Small Business  Office Supplies Paper   """While you Were Out"" Message Book, One Form per Page"    Wrap Bag    0.35    2011-06-08  
7100    50657   2011-12-18  High    16  60.02   0.1 Express Air 0.94    3.71    1.93    Aleksandra Gannaway New Brunswick   Atlantic    Corporate   Office Supplies Paper   """While you Were Out"" Message Book, One Form per Page"    Wrap Bag    0.35    2011-12-20
```

I want to load this file into the table that I created (the table doesn't contains all fields of the records). However, only one record is being loaded. How can I fix it?

```
CREATE DATABASE superstore;
SHOW DATABASES;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS superstore.orders;

CREATE TABLE superstore.orders(
OrderID int,
ProductID   int,
OrderDate   date,
OrderPriority   varchar(20),
OrderQuantity   int,
Sales   decimal(15, 5),
Discount    decimal(3, 2),
ShipMode    varchar(20),
Profit  decimal(15, 2),
UnitPrice   decimal(15, 2),
ShippingCost    decimal(15, 2)
);

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/gz/wcd/WCD-Toolbox-B5-SQL/data/superstore/orders.txt'
INTO TABLE superstore.orders
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(OrderID, ProductID, OrderDate, OrderPriority, OrderQuantity, Sales, Discount, ShipMode, Profit, UnitPrice, ShippingCost);

SELECT * FROM superstore.orders LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Use a hex dump of the file to make sure that `\n` is the line separator.

Comment: **1**. What is your OS? **2**. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69700/using-mysqls-load-infile-to-only-populate-certain-columns

Comment: @Barmar I just google what is a hex dump and try xxd myfile, it doesn't show any symbol like \n \t. How can I check what the separator is?

Comment: Use `od -c myfile` , it will show the escape sequences for control characters

Comment: @Barmar Cool! The seperator is /r. It works now. Thank you!